# Handling 207 (Multi-status) return code of PHP Curl

Tags: php, curl, webdav

I am currently using PHP Curl library to upload/download files to our WebDav server. I use PROPFIND to check if a certain directory is already existing in the WebDav server. However, it returns 207 HTTP Code (Multi-status) when the directory is already existing.

```
$ch = curl_init($destUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, implode(':', $credentials));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PROPFIND');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Depth: 0'));
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // 207
curl_close($ch);
```

How can I get all the status codes return by the command and not just the last one?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible with cURL alone.

Comment: You send one HTTP request, so your get one HTTP response. What "all the status codes" do you mean? Do you mean the WebDAV code in the response?

Comment: yes webdav code. When I tried  it via command line, aside from 207 I also got 200 which is actually what I would like to check.